Who owns rights to patent GB260015414?
I was told that a biomedical company has ownership or exclusive rights to Patent GB260015414. I don't know if it is a mechanical device or a chemical process? Just that it is valuable. If I can't find out if it is similar to an idea of mine can I at least find the name of the company holding it?

Could you check the patent's number. Neither Google Patents nor Espacenet have a patent or application with that number. Alternatively is you tell us the biomedical companies name, we could look up all its patents.

The owner of a patent at the time of issue for a patent is written on its face. and also easy to look up the current recorded owner.  Recordation of assignments is not required in the UK so the true owner at a moment in time is not easy to determine.

My issue was that I couldn’t find the document either on Google Patents or Espacenet.
